# having problems with \frac command

Tags: fractions

in my formula I have typed , the first term , SF1 ,doesn't go above the nominator line,

```
A11 = \frac{ \frac{\sum SF_{1_{i}}}{E}}{\epsilon_{11}}
```

could you please help me spot the problem?

I hope this is not a band type of question

Comment: [No problem here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJSqr.png)...

Comment: I see the same thing as Werner.

Comment: If it isn't working, you should post a MWE so we can recreate the problem.

Comment: are you using latex (not tex) ?

Comment: well the answer to my question , down here solved it , I use texmaker for latex , is that what you meant ?

Comment: reading between the lines of the question, answer, and comments, what is wanted is a "display style" sum in the numerator of a fraction, rather than the default "text style" with limits to the side.

Comment: As it stands this question is entirely unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{1_{i}}}{E}}{\epsilon_{11}}
```

If understand your question well, it can solve your problem.

Comment: It's not clear at all how this solves anything... we don't even know what the problem was...

Comment: I'm happy to help. For the sake of reference, please mark the answer as correct, ok?

Comment: oh sorry that I did not notice that I haven't